# Dynamic HashTable from a list in PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pnp-powershell

Rather than create a static HashTable that is composed of the data from my list, I am looking to make it dynamic, but ran into some difficulty in constructing it.

For example:

Given that $items is set to Get-PnPListItem

```
foreach($item in $items){
    $HashTable += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Title' = $item.FieldValues.Title;
        'Date' = $item.FieldValues.Date;
        'Column 3' = $item.FieldValues.Column_x0020_3;
        'Column 4' = $item.FieldValues.Column_x0020_4;
        'Assigned To' = $item.FieldValues.Assigned_x0020_To.LookupValue;
    }
}
```

That example above works, but again, is explicit.
My thought was to construct the HashTable from the All Items view.

```
$view = Get-PnPView -List $listName -Identity "All Items";
$columns = $view.ViewFields;
```

Since a foreach() cannot be run inside of the HashTable, I have tried piping Add and Add-Member from a foreach of $column in $columns, but without resolve.

Within the loop, I would also need to check each GetType() to determine if I need to append a .LookupValue, etc.

While I can get by with what I have and use explicit scripts, it should be self-evident how valuable a dynamically constructed script would be for all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
$listName="TestList"
$items=Get-PnPListItem -List $listName
$view = Get-PnPView -List $listName -Identity "All Items"
$columns = $view.ViewFields
$HashTable=@()
foreach($item in $items){
    $obj=New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $HashTable += $obj  
    foreach($column in $columns){
        if($column -eq "LinkTitle"){    
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value $item.FieldValues.Title
        }else{
            if($item.FieldValues[$column].toString() -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"){
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $column -Value $item.FieldValues[$column].LookupValue
            }else{
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $column -Value $item.FieldValues[$column]
            }

        }
    }           
}
```